# Python version check

Tags: python, django

When I did like this for checking python version installed

```
python -version
```

the result was like this-

```
Python 2.7.6
```

when I checked like this-

```
python -v
```

result was like this-

```
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.py
import _sysconfigdata_nd # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py
import sitecustomize # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.pyc
import encodings # directory /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
>>>
```

It looks like I have multiple versions of python installed which are causing problems while installing modules using pip. Even after installing django manage.py runserver shows error regarding unable to find django.core something something. How to solve this problem? Please help!!

Answer (score 3):

python -v is for 'verbose':

```
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
```

Note it is **lowercase**

`python -V` will give you the version. (uppercase v)

Answer (score 2):

You are using a lowercase `v` which means verbose, it is uppercase `V` for your version.